# HTML not posting file to PHP

Tags: php, html

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<div>
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
      <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
</div>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $file = $_POST["myFile"];
    echo("hello");
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

when I run it and input a file it says: Undefined array key "myFile"

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You failed to specify the proper `enctype` for your form, https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: You need `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded files don't get added to the $_POST array but they are loaded into the [$_FILES](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files) array. Try check that out.

You can then use the [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file) to save it wherever you want.

Important: as soon as the script execution is over, the temporary uploaded file is removed if it was not saved somewhere else with [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file).

Answer (score 0):

Add on form **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

This value is necessary if the user will upload a file through the form.

Your file type name is **"filename"**.

```
<html>
<body>

<div>
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
</div>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $file = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
    echo("hello");
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You won't find the file in the $_POST array, it will be added to $_FILES. This example would rise a NOTICE: Undefined index: filename in bla/bla/bla.php

Answer (score 0):

The request transfers the data using the names of the form fields and not the IDs, the file data can be found in the global variable $_FILES.

Use `$file = $_FILES['filename']['name'];` for the name of the uploaded file

or `$file = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];` for the temporary file path of the uploaded file.

Comment: You won't find the file in the $_POST array, it will be added to $_FILES.

Comment: Thanks Harvi you are right. Answer is changed.